# typescript decorator on nested class

Tags: typescript, decorator

How can one decorate a property on a nested class? Here's an example:

```
    function log(name: string = 'DecoratedProp') {
        return function logHandler(target: any, field: any) {
            // get the key
            Object.defineProperty(target, field, {
                get() {
                    console.info('Accessing:' + name, field)
                    return this[name];
                },
                set(value: any): void {
                    console.warn('Setting:' + name, field)
                    this[name] = value;
                }
            })
        };
    }
    class Nested {
        @log('Nested') data: string;
    }
    export class DecoratedModel {
        nested: Nested = {
            data: 'something',
            // decorating here won't work, e.g.
            // @log() somethingElse; -> breaks
        };
        @log() topLevel: string = '33';
    }
    const deco = new DecoratedModel();
    console.log(deco.topLevel);         // logs stuff
    console.log(deco.nested.data);      // doesn't log
```

Why is my nested property not decorated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are assigning a static object that matches the class interface, which satisfies the compiler, but has not got the decorated prototype as its not actually an instance of the class you decorated

You will need to instanciate the `Nested` class with `new` and it will work...

```
class Nested {
  @log('Nested') data: string;

  constructor(data: string) {
    this.data = data
  }
}

export class DecoratedModel {
  nested: Nested = new Nested('something');

  @log('toplevel') topLevel: string = '33';
}

const deco = new DecoratedModel();
console.log(deco2.topLevel); // logs
console.log(deco2.nested.data); // also logs!
```

Comment: Figured it was about the way I constructed the root class. But I figured exactly what is wrong with my code when you wrote the `prototype` word up there. I guess no other way to "deserialize" a big blob of JSON than writing one of those Reflect.metadata things I see around?